# SharpSNMP Implementation Based on snmptrad example stop working

Tags: c#, .net, snmp, unity-interception, sharp-snmp

I'm doing an application prototype based on a example included in Sharp-SNMP Library (snmptrapd) to get some data from SNMP protocol but has stopped working at all, by some unknown reason stopped working but don't throw any exception, compiles and execute well.

the problem resides in that the events never are rised.

**Dependences:**

- Unity Container from Microsoft
- SharpSNMP Library
- SourceGrid (Windows.Forms)

I had to note that until 2 days ago worked like a charm but now, I'm running out of ideas. (and i hadn't modified something radical in my code).

### C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Security;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Pipeline;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Mib;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Utility;
using System.Configuration;
using SourceGrid;

namespace Kraken
{
    public partial class frmConsola : Form
    {
        internal static IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }
        private SnmpEngine engine;

        // Delegates ....
        private delegate void MostrarMensajeDelegate(SourceGrid.Grid oGrd, DateTime eventTime, String eventType, IPAddress agentAddress, String Elemento, String Valor);

        public frmConsola()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.crear_demonio_trampas();
            this.crear_grid();
        }

        private void crear_grid()
        {
            grdData.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            grdData.ColumnsCount = 6;
            grdData.FixedRows = 1;
            grdData.Rows.Insert(0);

            grdData[0, 0] = new SourceGrid.Cells.ColumnHeader("Id");
            grdData[0, 1] = new SourceGrid.Cells.ColumnHeader("Hora");
            grdData[0, 2] = new SourceGrid.Cells.ColumnHeader("Tipo");
            grdData[0, 3] = new SourceGrid.Cells.ColumnHeader("Agente");
            grdData[0, 4] = new SourceGrid.Cells.ColumnHeader("Elemento");
            grdData[0, 5] = new SourceGrid.Cells.ColumnHeader("Valor");
            grdData.AutoSizeCells();
        }

        public void MostrarMensaje(SourceGrid.Grid oGrd, DateTime eventTime, String eventType, IPAddress agentAddress, String Elemento, String Valor)
        {
            int r = 0;
            if (!oGrd.IsDisposed)
            {
                r = oGrd.Rows.Count;
                oGrd.Rows.Insert(r);
                oGrd[r, 0] = new SourceGrid.Cells.Cell(r.ToString(), typeof(string));
                oGrd[r, 1] = new SourceGrid.Cells.Cell("?", typeof(string));
                oGrd[r, 2] = new SourceGrid.Cells.Cell(eventType, typeof(string));
                oGrd[r, 3] = new SourceGrid.Cells.Cell(agentAddress.ToString(), typeof(string));
                oGrd[r, 4] = new SourceGrid.Cells.Cell(Elemento, typeof(string));
                oGrd[r, 5] = new SourceGrid.Cells.Cell(Valor, typeof(string));
                grdData.AutoSizeCells();
            }
            else
            {
                throw (new ObjectDisposedException(oGrd.Name.ToString()));
            }
        }

        private void crear_demonio_trampas()
        {
            Container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration("snmptrapd");
            var users = Container.Resolve<UserRegistry>();
            users.Add(new OctetString("neither"), DefaultPrivacyProvider.DefaultPair);
            users.Add(new OctetString("authen"), new DefaultPrivacyProvider(new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
            users.Add(new OctetString("privacy"), new DESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString("privacyphrase"),
                                                                         new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
            // -------------- Plantas de fuerza ----------------------
            users.Add(new OctetString("PCC"), DefaultPrivacyProvider.DefaultPair);
            users.Add(new OctetString("peacct"), DefaultPrivacyProvider.DefaultPair);
            // -------------------------------------------------------
            var trapv1 = Container.Resolve<TrapV1MessageHandler>("TrapV1Handler");
            trapv1.MessageReceived += WatcherTrapV1Received;
            var trapv2 = Container.Resolve<TrapV2MessageHandler>("TrapV2Handler");
            trapv2.MessageReceived += WatcherTrapV2Received;
            var inform = Container.Resolve<InformRequestMessageHandler>("InformHandler");
            inform.MessageReceived += WatcherInformRequestReceived;
            this.engine = Container.Resolve<SnmpEngine>();
        }

        private void WatcherInformRequestReceived(object sender, InformRequestMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sTipo = "";
            uint[] codigo;
            Object[] oParams = new Object[6];
            oParams[0] = this.grdData;
            oParams[1] = new DateTime(e.InformRequestMessage.TimeStamp);
            codigo = e.InformRequestMessage.Enterprise.ToNumerical();
            foreach (int num in codigo)
            {
                if (sTipo != null)
                    sTipo += ".";
                sTipo += num.ToString();
            }
            oParams[2] = sTipo;
            oParams[3] = null;
            oParams[4] = e.InformRequestMessage.Variables()[0].ToString();
            oParams[5] = "";
            BeginInvoke(new MostrarMensajeDelegate(MostrarMensaje), oParams);
        }

        private void WatcherTrapV2Received(object sender, TrapV2MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sTipo = "";
            uint[] codigo;
            Object[] oParams = new Object[6];
            oParams[0] = this.grdData;
            oParams[1] = new DateTime(e.TrapV2Message.TimeStamp);
            codigo = e.TrapV2Message.Enterprise.ToNumerical();
            foreach (int num in codigo)
            {
                if (sTipo != null)
                    sTipo += ".";
                sTipo += num.ToString();
            }
            oParams[2] = sTipo;
            oParams[3] = null;
            oParams[4] = e.TrapV2Message.Variables()[0].Id.ToString();
            oParams[5] = e.TrapV2Message.Variables()[0].Data.ToString();
            BeginInvoke(new MostrarMensajeDelegate(MostrarMensaje), oParams);
        }

        private void WatcherTrapV1Received(object sender, TrapV1MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sTipo = "";
            uint[] codigo;
            Object[] oParams = new Object[6];
            oParams[0] = this.grdData;
            oParams[1] = new DateTime(e.TrapV1Message.TimeStamp);
            codigo = e.TrapV1Message.Enterprise.ToNumerical();
            foreach (int num in codigo)
            {
                if (sTipo != null)
                    sTipo += ".";
                sTipo += num.ToString();
            }
            oParams[2] = sTipo;
            oParams[3] = e.TrapV1Message.AgentAddress;
            oParams[4] = e.TrapV1Message.Variables()[0].Id.ToString();
            oParams[5] = e.TrapV1Message.Variables()[0].Data.ToString();
            //DateTime eventTime, String eventType, IPAddress agentAddress, String infoText
            BeginInvoke(new MostrarMensajeDelegate(MostrarMensaje), oParams);
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.engine.Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 162));
            this.engine.Start();
            this.txtStatus.Text = "Iniciando Captura ...";
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.engine.Stop();
            this.txtStatus.Text = "... Finalizando Captura.";
        }

    }
}
```

### App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <unity>
      <namespace name="Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Pipeline"/>
      <namespace name="Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging"/>
      <namespace name="Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Security"/>
      <namespace name="Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Mib"/>
      <namespace name="Lextm.SharpSnmpLib"/>
      <assembly name="SharpSnmpLib"/>
      <assembly name="SharpSnmpLib.Engine"/>
      <assembly name="SharpSnmpLib.Mib"/>
      <aliases>
        <add alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>
      </aliases>
      <containers>
        <container name="snmptrapd">
          <!-- users -->
          <register type="UserRegistry">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="users" dependencyType="User[]"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <!-- message handler settings-->
          <register type="MessageHandlerFactory" name="MessageFactory">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="mappings">
                <array>
                  <!--here we only have four-->
                  <dependency name="TRAPV1"/>
                  <dependency name="TRAPV2"/>
                  <dependency name="INFORM"/>
                  <dependency name="ALL"/>
                </array>
              </param>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="HandlerMapping" name="TRAPV1">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="version" value="v1"/>
              <param name="command" value="TRAPV1"/>
              <param name="handler" dependencyType="IMessageHandler" dependencyName="TrapV1Handler"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="HandlerMapping" name="TRAPV2">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="version" value="v2,v3"/>
              <param name="command" value="TRAPV2"/>
              <param name="handler" dependencyType="IMessageHandler" dependencyName="TrapV2Handler"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="HandlerMapping" name="INFORM">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="version" value="v2,v3"/>
              <param name="command" value="INFORM"/>
              <param name="handler" dependencyType="IMessageHandler" dependencyName="InformHandler"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="HandlerMapping" name="ALL">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="version" value="*"/>
              <param name="command" value="*"/>
              <param name="handler" dependencyType="IMessageHandler" dependencyName="NullHandler"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="IMessageHandler" mapTo="TrapV1MessageHandler" name="TrapV1Handler">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </register>
          <register type="IMessageHandler" mapTo="TrapV2MessageHandler" name="TrapV2Handler">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </register>
          <register type="IMessageHandler" mapTo="InformRequestMessageHandler" name="InformHandler">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </register>
          <register type="IMessageHandler" mapTo="NullMessageHandler" name="NullHandler">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </register>
          <!-- application factory and its parts -->
          <register type="SnmpApplicationFactory">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <!--<param name="logger" />-->
              <param name="store" dependencyType="ObjectStore"/>
              <param name="membershipProvider" dependencyType="IMembershipProvider" dependencyName="Composed"/>
              <param name="factory" dependencyType="MessageHandlerFactory"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="ObjectStore">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </register>
          <!-- this is the membership provider -->
          <register type="IMembershipProvider" mapTo="ComposedMembershipProvider" name="Composed">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="providers">
                <array>
                  <dependency name="v1"/>
                  <dependency name="v2"/>
                  <dependency name="v3"/>
                </array>
              </param>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="IMembershipProvider" mapTo="Version1MembershipProvider" name="v1">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="getCommunity" dependencyType="OctetString" dependencyName="get"/>
              <param name="setCommunity" dependencyType="OctetString" dependencyName="set"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="IMembershipProvider" mapTo="Version2MembershipProvider" name="v2">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="getCommunity" dependencyType="OctetString" dependencyName="get"/>
              <param name="setCommunity" dependencyType="OctetString" dependencyName="set"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="IMembershipProvider" mapTo="Version3MembershipProvider" name="v3">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </register>
          <register type="OctetString" name="get">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="content" value="public"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="OctetString" name="set">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="content" value="public"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <!-- Engine -->
          <register type="SnmpEngine">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <constructor>
              <param name="factory" dependencyType="SnmpApplicationFactory"/>
              <param name="listener" dependencyType="Listener"/>
              <param name="group" dependencyType="EngineGroup"/>
            </constructor>
          </register>
          <register type="Listener">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
            <property name="Users" dependencyType="UserRegistry"/>
          </register>
        </container>
      </containers>
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug, first please be familiar with the pipeline model,

http://www.lextm.com/2010/11/honeycell-drops-snmp-pipeline-and-our.html

Then, attach the debugger and check whether the ListenerBinding (https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/Messaging/ListenerBinding.cs) you use receives any SNMP packets from the wire.

After that, move on to next object of the pipeline SnmpApplication (https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/Pipeline/SnmpApplication.cs).

Step by step you might find out why no event is triggered.

Besides, you might also subscribe to SnmpEngine.ExceptionRaised to see if any exception occurs.